# jQuery check if a file exist locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a local site for a company (only local internal use, offline and without server). I have a main page that has a main div, that contain 3 different div. Each div is linked to a page and the "onclick" event of each div will load the page linked into the main div. So i have to check, with the document ready function, if each page exists and, if not, I want to delete the div linked to that page. How can I check if a page exist locally? I've found many answere that check with status of connection if a page exists, but my html will only work offline and locally, so I can't use that method.

**EDIT - SOLVED**

I've solved this using the script of @che-azeh:

```
function checkIfFileLoaded(fileName) {
    $.get(fileName, function(data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success") {
            // execute a success code
            console.log("file loaded!");
        }
    });
}
```

If the file was successfully load, i'd change the content of a new hidden div that will tell to another script if it have to remove or not each of the three div.

Comment: Offline means no internet connection then you can only check about the files on your local web server & not the outside world's

Comment: i have no local web server. it's a local site. i have html pages in directories, like they are .txt file. no web server, no connection, nothing. I only use pages linked with absolute path

Comment: you mean you are running that file in your browser with a URL like `file:///C:/xxx/xxx/fileCheck.html` or how ?

Comment: yes, exactly. and I have to check if file:///C:/xxx/xxx/page2.html exists

Comment: but your company would be running that on a web server,they wont be accessing like that URL ?

Comment: A website is made to run on a web server typically & I think you should be following that.Installing some local web server like WAMP or IIS & then running it

Comment: it's a kind of document that will be used internally. they want it in html becouse it's easy to use then and "good looking", but it will never be ran on a server. as i said, they have a server-version yet and it doesn't works properly, so they asked me to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function checks if a file can load successfully. You can use it to try loading your local files:

```
function checkIfFileLoaded(fileName) {
    $.get(fileName, function(data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success") {
            // execute a success code
            console.log("file loaded!");
        }
    });
}
checkIfFileLoaded("test.html");
```

Comment: Works! thanks! I have to check if it fails, so I only have to change the (textStatus == "success") with (textStatus != "success").

Comment: @FedericoPessina try this on chrome?

Comment: @techie_28 Firefox

Comment: @FedericoPessina Im suggesting you to run this on Google Chrome

Comment: @FedericoPessina run it and see yourself

Comment: on firefox it's working properly, but i can't use the "!="

Comment: @raphaëλ perhaps the "leaders" are ok with FireFox.. ;)

Comment: @techie_28 true :)

Comment: @FedericoPessina what you mean cant use `!=`? plus this way its never gonna be a stable solution ever unless you use a web server which is the proper way.

Comment: properly is wrong saying "cant use". I've tried to use the != to check if textstatus is not success, but it won't work

Comment: @FedericoPessina you are ok with this not working in Chrome?

Comment: @techie_28, it works on chrome. @Federico you cannot use `!=` due to asynchronous behaviors with JavaScript. [See why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). I suggest you execute your code based on the availability of the file and not otherwise.

Comment: Just found out chrome also has an option. I have updated my post to include this information about firefox and chrome

Comment: @raphaëλ  Perhaps the `leaders` would know of that option too.. ;)

Comment: You may try implementing a similar mechanism with a `promise` that would return success or failure upon promise completion. I think that should work on all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you run a **local web server** on the client's computer. (See also edit below on local XHR access).

With a local web server they can start it up as if it was an application. You could for example use  node's `http-server`. You could even install it as an node/npm package, which makes deployment also easier.

By using a proper http server (locally in your case) you can use xhr requests:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        async: true,
        url: "http://localhost:7171/myapp/somefile.html"
    }).done(function(){
        console.log("found");
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("not found");
    })
})
```

## EDIT:

#### Firefox

Another post has (@che-azeh) has brought to my attention that firefox *does* allow XHR on the file "protocol". At the time of this writing the above works in firefox using a `url` of just `somefile.html` and using the file scheme.

#### Chrome

Chrome has an option *allow-file-access-from-files* (http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/). This also allows local XHR request
This flag is intended for testing purposes:

> you should be able to run your tests in Google Chrome with no hassles

I would still suggest the local web server as this make you independent of these browser flags plus protect you from regression once firefox/chrome decide to disable support for this.

Comment: there is a site running with a server yet, but they want me to do the same  without it becouse it is better to navigate, and there are problems with using server here.

Comment: Yes so i suggest you run the WEB (node) server on the local machine and the access it using `http://localhost/etc`

Comment: I can't explain it here, but i really can't use any type of server

Comment: Ok, but you understand i am not talking about a remote server as in a computer right? I just mean an application running local on the client's machine that serves your web application, no external networking etc (just making sure here you understand what i mean ;)

Comment: yes i got it, but leaders want me to do it without any type of server. I will try to use the try-catch contruct in a hidden div. Could it works?

Comment: Make sure when you talk to your "leaders" that they also understand what is meant with a "local web server" in this context. As to `try/catch`, no i don't think that will work (what are you going place inside the `try/catch`?

Comment: yes they got it.
 
i would try to load the page into a hidden div, and in cathc i would delete the right div if it fail to load it

Comment: `$(…).load(…)` also uses xhr, it won't work with the `file` uri scheme

Comment: @FedericoPessina  It wont because you are intending to use it on URL like `file:///C:/xxx/xxx/fileCheck.html`.Ajax call will fail on URL like that as part of security policy you better look for some other solution like system based software etc for this

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to load the page within a `try-catch` construct. If the page exists, it will be loaded though. If it doesn't, you can (within the `catch`) set the related div as `hidden`.

Comment: I explained wrong it, going to edit.
edited. 
I can't use the try-catch construct: doing it, page that exists will be load into my main div befor clicking on that div.

Comment: What would OP have to place inside the `try-catch`?

Comment: Loading pages is asynchronous, you can't catch the error with `try-catch`.

Comment: Ooops... you are right @Barmar. Still, it could be done with a promise instead but following the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the page using `$.ajax`. Use the `error:` option to run a callback function that removes the DIV linked to the page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page1.html",
    error: function() {
        $("#page1_div").remove();
});
```

You can loop this code over all the DIVs.

Comment: he is accesing the files with URL's like `file:///C:/xxx/xxx/fileCheck.html`,I doubt ajax call will go through like that?

Comment: '<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "artisan.html",
      error: function() {
      $("#div_artisan").remove();
     });
   });
 </script>'

like so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `load` function

```
$("div").load("/test.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $(this).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```